# Partial mocking parent-child classes

Tags: java, easymock

I have the following scenario which I would like to unit-test:

```
class Base {
  public void doWork(Consumer<Pipe> consumer) {
    try {
      Pipeline pipeline = acquirePipeline()
      consumer.accept(pipeline);
      pipeline.sync();
    } finally {
      unlock();
    }
  }
}

class Worker extends Base {
  // whatever...
}


class Service {
  private Worker worker = ..

  public void handle() {
    worker.doWork((p) -> {
      // run some code...
    };

  }
```

My test code

```
class ServiceTest {
  public test() throws Exception {
     
     Worker worker = newMock(Worker.class);
     worker.whileLocked(any(Runnable));
     reply(worker);

     Service service = new Service(worker);
     service.handle();

     verify(worker);
  }
}
```

I have partially mocked `Worker`, but in order for the code in `Service` to run properly, I cannot mock `doWork` (I think), and if I don't mock it then I'll get `NullPointerException` when the code runs `doWork` because the data members are not initialized.

Any idea how to handle such a case?

Answer (score 1):

Can you consider using `Mockito` instead of `EasyMock`?

In that case, there is a way to call a real method on mocked classes.

```java
doCallRealMethod().when(worker).whileLocked(any(Runnable.class));
```

I don't use `EasyMock` and I tried to find something to help but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to find a similar solution using EasyMock with `partialMockBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

When creating a partial mock with EasyMock, you can call the constructor of your class with the `partialMockBuilder`. But I think you figured that out.